# Why PHP lose item value of array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the array with values:

```
$array1 = array('Boss', 'Lentin', 'Endless'); 
print_r ($array);
```

The result will be:

```
Array ( [0] => Boss [1] => Lentin [2] => Endless
```

It's ok.

But, if I add two elements to this array with a keys, the "Boss" element will be lost.

```
$array2 = array("1"=>'Doctor','Boss', 2=>'Lynx', 'Lentin', 'Endless');
print_r ($array2);
```

The result will be:

```
Array ( [1] => Doctor [2] => Lynx [3] => Lentin [4] => Endless ) 
//Where is "BOSS"???
```

Why?

Comment: Syntax is important. So is looking at your error log when things dont work!

Comment: There is no any errors and syntax problems.

Comment: You will need to create a two dimensional array to store more than one value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When php create the array, set `Doctor` in index 1 and `Boss` in index 2, but `2=>'Lynx'` cause php overwrite index 2 and set `Lynx` in it.

You can set it after setted index or use index for it. For example like

```
$array2 = array("1"=>'Doctor', 2=>'Lynx', 'Boss', 'Lentin', 'Endless');
// or 
$array2 = array("1"=>'Doctor', 2=>'Boss', 3=>'Lynx', 'Lentin', 'Endless');
```

Answer (score 5):

When $array is being created, 'Boss' will first be stored in index 2 `(Array([2] =>'Boss')` which is later overwritten by 'Lynx'

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is index keys

```
$array2 = array("1"=>'Doctor','Boss', 2=>'Lynx', 'Lentin', 'Endless');
print_r ($array2);
```

This is because, on index 1 it is already doctor, boss will be second, which will be replaced by Lynx which have same index of 2 where boss will be replaced.

I hope I am clear.

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behaviour from php (see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-57). In case you need all the values in the array and don't need to work with keys, I recommend to use `array_push($array $value)`. Otherwise you should add all the values with their keys and remember that for PHP `1` and `"1"` and `true` are the same values so they will overwrite each other.

Comment: Which manual do you mean? In the link that I posted there is stated: "As all the keys in the above example are cast to 1, the value will be overwritten on every new element and the last assigned value "d" is the only one left over.".  ==> In your example you firstly set `"1"=>'Doctor'` so the key is forced to `1`. Next one is without key so only the value of the previous one is incremented to `2`. You continue with setting `2=>'Lynx'` but the key `2` is already used for `Boss` and that's why it is replaced with new value `Lynx`. In the end `Boss` is missing from the array altogether.

Answer (score 2):

[array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) is a construct with dynamic arguments representing literal arrays. The assignment of the given values to the array structure is done **sequentially** i.e. one by one from left to right. In your example:

1. `Doctor` is assigned to index 1.
2. `Boss` is assigned to index 2.
3. `Lynx` overwrites index 2.
4. `Lentin` and `Endless` are assigned to index 3 and 4 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

> hey @Weltkind first of all i suggest you to read
>   "http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php",

now come to your answer In php the array key can be string or integer and if you do not mention the key then 
default integer is set and the value of next array key is depending on the previous array integer key means

next array key = previous integer key + 1;

In PHP array the same key value will override by the same key

> Now lets understand with your array2:

```
<?php
$array2 = array("1"=>'Doctor','Boss', 2=>'Lynx', 'Lentin', 'Endless');
```

> 1) as you started your array with key "1" so the
>
> so for 1st key value is  [1] => 'Doctor'
>
> current array like:   array([1] => 'Doctor')

now next key = previous integer key(that is 1) + 1 = 2;

> 2) for 2nd key value is [2] => 'BOSS'
>
> current array like:   array([1] => 'Doctor', [2] => 'BOSS')
>
> 3) next key = previous integer key(that is 2) + 1 = 3 it will carry
>   to next key but as next key is [2] => 'Lynx' as you mentioned so at
>   key [2] the value will be override by value 'BOSS' to 'Lynx'; current
>   array like : array([1] => 'Doctor', [2] => 'Lynx')

Now the next key we have is [3]

> 4) for next value the key is [3] => 'Lentin'
>
> current array like :  array([1] => 'Doctor', [2] => 'Lynx', [3] =>
>   'Lentin');
>
> now next key = previous integer key(that is 3) + 1 = 4;
>
> 5) for next value the key is [4] => 'Endless'
>
> current array like :  array([1] => 'Doctor', [2] => 'Lynx', [3] =>
>   'Lentin', [4] => 'Endless');

and that is why the final array is like below :

```
array(
        [1] => 'Doctor', 
        [2] => 'Lynx', 
        [3] => 'Lentin', 
        [4] => 'Endless'
    );
```